# Css tooltip highlight one word not whole text

Tags: html, css

In the code below the tooltip highlight the whole text relative to it. How can I highlight only word "over".

```css
body {text-align: center}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h2>Top Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

The code above was extracted from here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your HTML a bit:

```css
body {text-align: center}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  /*display: inline-block; not necessary*/
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h2>Top Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div>Hover <span class="tooltip">over<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></span> me
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was expecting. I did not want to "touch" anything else, only the word(s) I want to hightlight. And your code does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can edit html, you can just wrap the word `over` with given class.

```
Hover <div class="tooltip">over<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></div> me
```

**Edited:**

```
<div>Hover <span class="tooltip">over<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></span> me</div>
```

Comment: Hello Arvind.Your code works, except that "div" should be replaced by "span" so that it do not breaks line. Thanks for the help.